# ASP.net web config mail settings

Tags: email

I've got a website hosted on godaddy. I've got a page that sends email from the user to me. It works in local host but not when I deploy it. It glitches on the mail settings part of webconfig. I had been trying to use my godaddy mail account but could not get that to work at all. I then created a gmail account and used that for my mail server. that works fine in local host but not when I deploy it. I've tried all the different combinations of settings for defaultcredentials, enableSSl, etc. but can't get it to work. Here's my mail settings code (this works in local host):

```
<system.net>

<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com"  enableSsl="true" port="587" userName="****@gmail.com" password="****"></network>

  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't write your real login !!!!!

(ps: The used port is maybe locked on your distant server)